# jQuery dropdown menu animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, drop-down-menu

I have the typical submenu structure:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Parent link</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Submenu link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and in design/html mockups, I would use CSS3 transitions to animate the submenus but since `pointer-events: none` isn't a practical alternative for `display: none`, this method isn't great for live sites.

I figure jQuery would be the only way to create the cross-browser animation I want.  When the parent `<li>` is hovered, I want the submenu to go from 0 opacity to 100, but also rise up with a margin change.

I know it sounds confusing, but here's a basic version of what I'm looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/jwq5R/ (only works correctly in browsers that support `pointer-events` and CSS3 transitions) but only with the animation done with jQuery.

I researched and I just can't get anything to work so far to get the effect I want.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/jwq5R/1/

```
$(function(){
    $('#nav>li').hover(function() {
        $(this).closest('li').find('>ul').css({
            'opacity': 0,
            'margin-top': 15
        }).show().animate({
            'margin-top': 0,
            'opacity': 1
        }, 300);
    }, function() {
        $(this).closest('li').find('>ul').fadeOut(200, function() {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Your jsfiddle is brilliant, except I can't even get it to work...
I copied/pasted all of your code exactly and still nothing. I'm not seeing the issue.

This is what I have: http://scferg.com/menutest.html

Comment: @user984008: You need `<html>`/`</html>` and more importantly a doctype as the very first line, such as `<!DOCTYPE html>`. You also need to use [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: @user984008 updated my code. you forgot the jquery .ready() as thirtydot said